# Python using braces inside list brackets

Tags: python

Im very new to Python and finding it very different to anything ive encountered before coming from the PHP realm.

**Background**:

Ive searched SO and [learned that the differences between:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391419/what-is-the-difference-between-curly-brace-and-square-bracket-in-python)

`x = [] and x{}` is that the brackets will create a list and the curly braces is for creating a series. What I could not find however is an explination for the following

**Question**

Why does this piece of code use braces inside a list with brackets like so:

`context.modules[(stock, length)] = 0`

Why the braces inside the list?

And then as a "bonus help" if I may why set it to 0 (although that's probably out of scope of question)

Fullcode:

```
context.modules = {}
    for stock in context.stock_list:
        for length in context.channels:
            context.modules[(stock, length)] = 0
```

Comment: Round braces contains a tuple type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dictionary, as you understand:

```
In [463]: dct = {'a' : 1}

In [464]: dct['a']
Out[464]: 1
```

It has one key-value entry. The key is a `str` type. `str`s are allowed to be keys for a dictionary because they can be *hashed* because they are immutable and their objects yield a unique, unchanging hash value which the dictionary uses to index the object for fast access.

Similarly, `int`s, `float`s, `bool`s, basically anything that is *immutable* may be a key. This includes *`tuples`*, but not structures such as `list`s, `set`s and `dict`s.

Now, here's a tuple:

```
In [466]: x = (1, 2)
```

`x` can be used as the key in a dictionary.

```
In [469]: d = {x : 5}

In [470]: d
Out[470]: {(1, 2): 5}
```

To access the value associated with the `tuple`, you'd index with it:

```
In [471]: d[(1, 2)]
Out[471]: 5
```

This is the basic meaning behind that syntax you ask about. It is interesting to note that the parenthesis are optional:

```
In [472]: d[1, 2]
Out[472]: 5
```

This is because the parenthesis do not demarcate a `tuple`, but the comma `,` does.

Comment: very interesting. Got lots to learn. Thank You. Will accept once time expires

Answer (score 1):

Your `context.modules` is not a list, it's a python [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) (map in most other languages)

So, when you're doing this:

```
context.modules[(stock, length)] = 0
```

You're basically creating a *key, value* pair in the dictionary, with `key` as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) of `(stock, length)` and value as `0`.

Considering

`stock = 2` and `length = 5`

your `context.modules` after the above assignment, will look like this:

```
>>> context.modules
{(2, 5): 0}
```